# Using jquery to load header on each page and subnav menu items are not showing

Tags: java, html, jquery, css, web

Like the title says, I'm using jquery to load the header on each page of a website. I need to be able to update the header through one file because right now I have to go into EVERY page every time they want to, for example, add a new page on the navbar. But with the load function, the submenu links are not showing up on hover. However, when it's hardcoded on the page it works just fine. Does any know why this might be? I've tried to include all relevant code below.

This is the script I am using:

```
    <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#header").load("header.html");
    });
    </script>
```

How it is coded in index.html and other webpages:

```
<div id="header"></div>
```

How header.html is coded:

```html
<header>
  <h1>
    <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo-full-dark-01.png" alt="" /></a>
  </h1>
  <nav id="nav">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="visit.html" class="submenu fa-angle-down">Visit</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="visit.html">Direction &amp; Hours</a></li>
          <li><a href="visit-tours.html">Tours</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="exhibitions-current.html" class="submenu fa-angle-down">Exhibitions</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="exhibitions-permanent.html">Permanent</a></li>
          <li><a href="exhibitions-current.html">Current</a></li>
          <li><a href="exhibitions-upcoming.html">Upcoming</a></li>
          <li><a href="exhibitions-past-2021.html">Past</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Note: I did not create this website, just trying to help manage it at this point. Everything was hard coded so I'm trying to transition to this jQuery solution.

Comment: If there is javascript that adds functionality to the menu, it could be that that runs when `#header` is still empty before the `.load()` function completes. If that's the case then you need to make sure that the nav js runs after the header html is loaded with the callback parameter of the jquery load function https://api.jquery.com/load/#load-url-data-complete

Answer (score 0):

If the nav items aren't showing up on hover, it might be a css issue. Check the browser devtools console to see if the css styles are loading correctly. Try pasting this into the template to see if the nav subitems show when nav is hovered.

```
<style>
    #nav li {
        position: relative;
    }
    #nav li ul {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
        background-color: #eee;
    }
    #nav li ul li {
        display: block;
    }
    #nav li:hover > ul {
        display: block;
        min-width: 180px;
    }
</style>
```